# none of the jquery functions work even the correct files are loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, opencart

im having a strange problem. i just did a fresh installation of Opencart on my server and for some reason none of the jquery functions work.. sliders, popups and even the add to cart button or even a simple alert box dont work (i created a button with the ID test)

```
$( "#test" ).click(function() {
alert( "clicked" );
});
```

Below is how the theme files are loaded

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="catalog/view/theme/theme2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="catalog/view/theme/theme2/js/jquery.formstyler.js"></script>
    <script src="catalog/view/theme/theme2/js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.0-packed.js"></script>
    <script src="catalog/view/theme/theme2/js/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="catalog/view/theme/theme2/js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <script src="catalog/view/theme/theme2/js/jquery.minicolors.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/common.js"></script>
    <script src="catalog/view/theme/theme2/js/script.js"></script>
```

checked all the files and they are place correctly. no missing files. All are freshly uploaded.

i even changed to the default theme which hasnt been touched, but still same. when i even click on add to cart or any other button it doesnt work

i tried accessing the site with and without www , still it doesnt work

the main problem is it does not show any error though the console or firebug which makes it hard to debug. can someone tell me what might be causing this?

Comment: Wow that is terrible...too many header requests

Comment: post link where we can see the problem pls.

Comment: Can you try isolating the problem by removing all the script tags except for the first one since the `click` function should only be provided by the base jQuery file?

Comment: 1. open your site 2. open JS console 3. enter `console.log($("body").html());` 4. profit (jQuery seems to work here) --- right-click is blocked ... booooh --- I tried to search for an element with `id="test"` in your page, couldn't find it

Comment: @pixeline i added the url to the site - i changed to the theme from the default. strangely the slider works while the page is loading and once loaded it doenst work at all. thats it nothing else works

Comment: @wmock it works when i place in a html it works with the jquery base, but not in the theme even if i remove all other scripts

Answer (score 3):

Button #test does not exist on page load, so .click() function does not recognize it.
Try using .on():

```
$(document).on('click', '#test', function() {
    alert("clicked");
});
```

Comment: actually i created it in the default theme to test the functionality of add to cart - nothing happens even if i click it. you can see the problem here http://goo.gl/7d645j if clicked on add to cart or select the dropdowns nothing happens..

Comment: The link is working for me, you need to select size and fragrance before clicking Add to cart. I tested on Chrome windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment yet on SO, but @LiveEn, I tested your link and it works on Chrome x64 v39, Win. 8.1.

Onclick Add-to-cart: Size: * Size required!

Onclick Size select: Dropwsdown menu